# mongoose query to merge array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this:

collection base:

```
{
    _id:"a"
    field:[
        {
          _id:"aa",
          field1:"aa1"
        },
        {
          _id:"ab",
          field2:"ab2"
        },
    ]
}
```

what query can I use to have a result like this:

```
{
    _id:"a"
    field:            
        {
          _id:"ab",
          field2:"ab2",
          field1:"aa1"
        },        
}
```

In other words i want use this function as mongoose query on `field` array:

```
field.reduce((p,c)=>({...p,...c}),{})
```

Comment: on what base you want to select `_id:"ab"` why its not `_id:"aa"`?

Comment: i want to merge array items from start to end into one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `field`, set `initialValue` to empty object,
- `$mergeObjects` to merge `initialValue` means `$$value` and `$$this` means current object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      field: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$field",
          initialValue: {},
          in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9eeTnuWsL6a)